# MongoDB Track data changes

Tags: database, mongodb

I want to track changes on MongoDB Documents. The big Challenge is that MongoDB has nested Documents.

### Example

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "60f7a86c0e979362a25245eb",
    "email": "walltownsend@delphide.com",
    "friends": [
      {
        "name": "Hancock Nelson"
      },
      {
        "name": "Owen Dotson"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cathy Jarvis"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### after the update/change

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "60f7a86c0e979362a25245eb",
    "email": "walltownsend@delphide.com",
    "friends": [
      {
        "name": "Daphne Kline"     //<------
      },
      {
        "name": "Owen Dotson"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cathy Jarvis"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is a **very basic example** of a highly expandable real world use chase.

On a SQL Based Database, I would suggest some sort of [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1299793-how-to-structure-table-s-for-change-history) solution.

### The SQL way

**users**

| _id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | cathyjarvis@delphide.com |

**friends**

| _id | user_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | Hancock Nelson |
| 1 | 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | Suarez Burt |
| 2 | 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | Mejia Elliott |

#### after the update/change

**users**

| _id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | cathyjarvis@delphide.com |

**friends**

| _id | user_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | Daphne Kline |
| 1 | 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | Suarez Burt |
| 2 | 60f7a8b28db7c78b57bbc217 | Mejia Elliott |

**history**

| _id | friends_id | field | preUpdate | postUpdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | name | Hancock Nelson | Daphne Kline |

If there is an update and the change has to be tracked before the next update, this would work for NoSQL as well. If there is a second Update, we have a second line in the SQL database and it't very clear. On NoSQL, you can make a list/array of the full document and compare changes during the indexes, but there is very much redundant information which hasn't changed.

Comment: Do you like to track also new and removed elements or only updates of existing elements? If yes, do you have add/remove/modify at the same time?

Comment: In an array, the order matters. What happens if you get the same names, but just in a different order?

Comment: Yes, shure. Array = index. But for my example i only want the array, no matter which sorting the Database applies.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Set Expression Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-expression-operators)

- `$setDifference`
- `$setEquals`
- `$setIntersection`

Be ware, these operators perform set operation on arrays, treating arrays as sets. If an array contains duplicate entries, they ignore the duplicate entries. They ignore the order of the elements.

In your example the update would result in

```
removed: [ {name: "Hancock Nelson" } ],
added: [ {name: "Daphne Kline" } ]
```

If the number of elements is always the same before and after the update, then you could use this one:

```
db.collection.insertOne({
   friends: [
      { "name": "Hancock Nelson" },
      { "name": "Owen Dotson" },
      { "name": "Cathy Jarvis" }
   ],
   updated_friends: [
      { "name": "Daphne Kline" },
      { "name": "Owen Dotson" },
      { "name": "Cathy Jarvis" }
   ]
})


db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         difference: {
            $map: {
               input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$friends" }] },
               as: "i",
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: {
                        $eq: [
                           { $arrayElemAt: ["$friends", "$$i"] },
                           { $arrayElemAt: ["$updated_friends", "$$i"] }
                        ]
                     },
                     then: null,
                     else: {
                        old: { $arrayElemAt: ["$friends", "$$i"] },
                        new: { $arrayElemAt: ["$updated_friends", "$$i"] }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         difference: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$difference",
               cond: { $ne: ["$$this", null] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Look good, maybe that want I want. I will try this in the next days. In this example, you added a new field with array type at the users document?

Comment: Yes, this is more an example to visualize the function.